# Handle new version AngularJS web application

Tags: javascript, angularjs, spring

How do we handle new version of AngularJS web application?

**The context :** my application is a full Angular JS application, I use gulp for each new version (uglify, minify, etc...), a new version of my application is basically composed of index.html, myapp-v01122016.js, myapp-v01122016.css, lib-v01122016.js and lib-v01122016.css. For backend I am using Spring.

**My issue :** each time I release a new version, the users have to refresh their page on the web browser to have the new version of the application. This is causing a lot of useless support because I have a lot of users that do not logout or close their web browser each day, so they do not have last patched version. How can I do for the users to have always last patched version?

Answer (score 2):

You can attach a versionId/buildnumber to every request from the back end to the front end and grab that from the HttpInterceptor. Then crosscheck the number against the one stored in the localdb or cookie. If it is different then store the latest one and just reload the page for the user.

I don't know much about spring, but in C#/webApi it is quite easy to do and implement.

Answer (score 0):

Finally I use HTTP header "Last-Modified". 
When the user connects to the application I store in localStorage the value of the header "Last-Modified" for index.html, and then I have an angular process that will execute every hour abd which performs a HEAD HTTP request and compare the header "Last-Modified" of the HEAD response to the value stored in localStorage.